# Error at compile time during assignment of a std::string to template parameter

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, templates

I'm using C++ 11 with Visual Studio 2013. Here is my context: I would like to call a template method:

```
template<typename T> bool InvokeMyMethod(std::string methodName, T &retValue, int  modeType...)
```

and pass the template parameter as return value. In this way, I would call this function using integer, float, `std::string` parameters.
But, when I try to assign `std::string` to template parameter, I get an error. Here is my header and implementation code:

```
// include files ...

int  IncValue(int iParam)
{
return ++iParam;
}
float DivValue(float fParam)
{
return (fParam / 2);
}
const char* GetHello()
{
return "Hello\n";
}

template<typename T> bool InvokeMyMethod(std::string methodName, T &retValue, int  modeType...)
{
bool bRet = false;
switch (modeType)
{
case 0:  // basic
{
std::cout << " Method " << methodName << " correctly invoked ." << std::endl;
bRet = true;
}
break;
case 1:  //call int function
{
va_list args;
va_start(args, modeType);
int iParam = va_arg(args, int);
int result = IncValue(iParam);
va_end(args);
retValue = result;
bRet = true;
}
break;

case 2:   // call float function
{
va_list args;
va_start(args, modeType);
float fParam = (float)va_arg(args, double);
float result = DivValue(fParam);
va_end(args);
retValue = result;
bRet = true;
}
break;

case 3:  //call string function
{
    const char *strReturn = GetHello();
    std::string sValReturned;
    sValReturned = strReturn;
    std::cout << " Template for string : " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;

//HERE IS MY PROBLEM AT COMPILE TIME
retValue = sValReturned;  // if i comment this line, everything is  
                          // ok, otherwise i got compiling error            
                          // like: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert 
                          // from 'std::string' to 'int' 
                          // AND
                          // cannot convert from 'std::string' to 
                          // 'float'
    bRet = true;
}
break;
}
return bRet;
}
```

//**************** CPP :   MAIN *****************

```
// include files ...

int main()
{
std::string strMethod = "";
strMethod = "Method_A";
int iResult = 0;
int iParam = 10;
if (InvokeMyMethod(strMethod, iResult, 1,iParam))
{
    std::cout << " Invoke  Method " << strMethod << "  returns : " << iResult << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << " Error : Invoke Method " << strMethod << ". Method or Class not found!" << std::endl;
}

strMethod = "Method_B";
float fResult = 0;
float fParam = 9.0f;
if (InvokeMyMethod(strMethod, fResult, 2, fParam))
{
    std::cout << " Invoke  Method " << strMethod << "  returns : " << fResult << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << " Error : Invoke  Method " << strMethod << ". Method or Class not found!" << std::endl;
}

strMethod = "Method_C";
std::string sResult ="";
std::string sParam = "Hello";
if (InvokeMyMethod(strMethod, sResult, 3, sParam))
{
    std::cout << " Invoke  Method " << strMethod << "  returns : " << sResult << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << " Error : Invoke  Method " << strMethod << ". Method or Class not found!" << std::endl;
}


std::cout << "Press any key...";
std::cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

When I try to assign (in the .h file, in the template method) the string value to template parameter, I get the following error.

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'int'
>
> cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'float'

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Try InvokeMyMethod<std::string>(). You aren't supplying a template type.

Comment: A function template must typecheck in its entirety when it's instantiated - that is, all your switch-cases must be correct simultaneously for whatever type `T` happens to be. Runtime type-switching and templates don't mix.

Comment: Since `InvokeMyMethod` is in reality four completely independent functions and you select one of them through `modeType`, you could probably move that decision out of the function and write four different overloads instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use template specialization in this way:

```
template<typename T>
bool InvokeMyMethod(std::string methodName, T &retValue, int  modeType...)
{
    bool bRet = false;
    switch (modeType)
    {
    case 0:  // basic
    {
        std::cout << " Method " << methodName << " correctly invoked ." << std::endl;
        bRet = true;
    }
        break;
    case 1:  //call int function
    {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, modeType);
        int iParam = va_arg(args, int);
        int result = IncValue(iParam);
        va_end(args);
        retValue = result;
        bRet = true;
    }
        break;

    case 2:   // call float function
    {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, modeType);
        float fParam = (float)va_arg(args, double);
        float result = DivValue(fParam);
        va_end(args);
        retValue = result;
        bRet = true;
    }
        break;

    }
    return bRet;
}

template<>
bool InvokeMyMethod(std::string methodName, std::string &retValue, int  modeType...) {
    bool bRet = false;
    const char *strReturn = GetHello();
    std::string sValReturned;
    sValReturned = strReturn;

    retValue = sValReturned;

    bRet = true;
    return bRet;
}
```

Comment: Hi Danilo, thank you for your answer. It works! Great! But ... what is the problem in my previous code?

Comment: Hello, I'm glad my answer helped you. I believe the problem is in the use of C++ templating, without using template specialization for non-native types (like int, float, double...). Infact, in the same function, you assigned retValue to different types (both native and complex) and this "type inference" issue raised only for the complex type (std::string) assignment.